# How to convert the steamwriter code in C# to python

Tags: python, streamwriter

I have written c# code and i need this to be written in python but i dont no how to use stream writer in python.Please help me how to use the stream writer functionality in python

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(val);
                            tw.WriteLine(" used.");
                            tw.WriteLine();
                            tw.WriteLine("02");
                            tw.Write(unit.ToString("X8") + " ");
                            tw.Write(result.Length.ToString("X4"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation on StreamWriter here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/StreamWriter

```
var tw = StreamWriter(val)
      tw.write(" used.\n");
      tw.write("\n");
      tw.write("02\n");
      ...
```

If it is simply string manipulation i suggest: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html

Comment: thanks it is working fine then how can we use b.ToString("X2") in python

Comment: What is the type of b and what is the desired output? You have methods such as hex() to print hexidecimal values.

Comment: here b is a datatype of byte and in python how can we define and assign a byte datatype

Comment: Python does not really have a byte data type. Try `hex(b)` or look at: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation or https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module; I believe it will largely do what you want.